# Does this hold in general?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, volume

I know the following holds when $n=1$. What about the case of $n \geq 2$?

Let $O \subsetneq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a nonempty open set.

There exists $C, \delta >0$ such that $|\{x \in O \mid \operatorname{dist}(x, \mathbb{R} \setminus O) < \varepsilon\}| \geq C {\varepsilon}^n$ for all $0<\varepsilon < \delta$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YES. Assume $S\ne \Bbb R^n.$

(I). Terminology. Let $m(S)$ denote the $n$-dimensional measure of any  measurable  $S\subset \Bbb R^n.$ For $x\in \Bbb R^n$ and $r>0$ let $B(x,r)$ be the open ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$ . Let $r^n C_n$ be the volume (measure) of $B(x,r).$ Let $C=2^{-n}C_n.$

Let $O^c=\Bbb R^n$ \ $O.$ For brevity let $\{x\in O: d(x, O^c)< e\}=S(e).$

(II). Take $d>0$ small enough that there exists $x_0\in O$ with $d(x_0,O^c)=d.$

For any $e\in (0,d)$   take $x_1\in \{tx_0+(1-t)q:t\in [0,1]\}$ such that $d(x_1,q)=e/2.$ Note that $d(x_0,x_1)=d-e/2.$

Now $B(x_1,e/2)\subset O .$ Otherwise,  if $y\in B(x_1,e/2)\cap O^c$ then $$d(x_0,O^C)\leq d(x_0,y)\leq d(x_0,x_1)+d(x_1,y)=(d-e/2)+d(x_1,y)< (d-e/2)+e/2=d.$$

So  for any $x\in B(x_1,e/2)$ we have $x\in O$ and $$d(x,O^c)\leq d(x,q)\leq d(x,x_1)+d(x_1,q)<e/2+d(x_1,q)=e. $$

Therefore $B(x_1,e/2)\subset S(e).$

Therefore $m(S(e))\geq m(B(x_1,e/2)=Ce^n.$

Footnote. $U=O^c \cap \overline {B(x_0,1+d)}$ is compact  so some $q\in U$ satisfies $d(x_0,q)=d(x_0, O^c) .$

Comment: Thank you very much, but your proof seems to be unclear. Could you please check?

Comment: What part(s) of it are unclear to you?

Comment: Sentence of more below (Ⅱ).

Comment: Could you be more specific.please?

Comment: What is your claim in (Ⅱ)?

Comment: (II) proves $S(e)\subset S(e/2)$,  which is used in (III).

Comment: Did you use the assumption in  proof by contradiction? Or, your claim is that is always true?

Comment: If  the main proposition is false, then for every $ d>0$ there exists $e\in (0,d)$ such that $S(e)\subset S(e/2), $  which implies (as shown in  $(III)$) that    there exists $d$ with $d<d.$

Comment: You say you used  'for each $d>0$ we may take  $e\in (0,d)$ such that $m(S(e))<Ke^n=C_n (e/2)^n$'?

Comment: Which implies that if $x\in S(e)$ then the  open ball $ B(x,e)/2)$ can't be a subset of $S(e),$ else $m(S(e))\geq m(B(x.e/2))=Ke^n$.... So there exists $y\in B(x,e/2) \setminus S(e)$.... Then we show that this $y$ can't belong to $O,$ so it belongs to $O^c,$ and this implies that $d(x, O^c)\leq d(x,y)<e/2.$ And conclude that  if $x\in S(e)$ then  $x\in S(e/2)$.

Comment: Did you use $d(x, O^c) < \frac{e}{2}$?

Comment: In my previous comment  we have $y\in O^c $ so $d(x,O^c)\leq  d(x,y),$ But $d(x,y)<e/2$ because we also have $y\in B(x,e/2).$ Hence $d(x.O^c)\leq d(x,y)<e/2.$

Comment: What I mean is that you used that under the assumption $y \in O$.

Comment: OOPS. That is a serious error on my part. I have a fix but it will require a total re-write, which I will do later today. It's 10:30 A.M. here.

Comment: I would appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: Tomorrow. For sure.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much.

Comment: GOT IT. I had to re-do it . The idea is that for every sufficiently small $e>0$ there is an open ball of radius $e/2$ that is a subset of $S(e).$.

Comment: I would appreciate your help. Thank you very much.